# How to extract data from column B when column A data is at max? In R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame here. I need to extract the day of the week that had the maximum return.
I have tried this code but it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have a solution?

```
print(DF$TrdWeekdays[max(DF$VWRet_DF)])
```

[image: Data Frame]

Answer (score 1):

We need `which.max` instead of `max`

```
 DF$TrdWeekdays[which.max(DF$VWRet_DF)]
```

Or another option is `==`

```
DF$TrdWeekdays[DF$VWRet_DF == max(DF$VWRet_DF)]
```